# What does Velocity in nav_msgs/Odometry actually mean?

Tags: ros, nav-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am confused with this type of data. What does the twist.twist.linear.x and twist.twist.linear.y actually represent?

I have a robot that can move either forward or backward and can ofcourse turn. In that case, doesn't the robot exhibit just velocity along X direction. Even if it turns, the robot's frame turns as well, still giving it a linear velocity along X direction. How come I am getting both X and Y velocity values here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238659/what-does-velocity-in-nav_msgs/odometry-actually-mean?/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2016-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your understanding is correct. For a differential drive robot, the odom.twist.twist.linear.y = 0 as it is referred to the base_link frame.
The other part of the Odometry message though will include X and Y position in the Odom frame.

See this page where the to different frames are called out. http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html

As to why you are getting X and Y velocities, you'll have to provide some info on what your setup is.

.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2016-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on 2016-07-04**:
Thanks for your reply! I have a differential robot that follows a path. Child frame id is base_footprint. I am getting X,Y lin vel and Z for ang. vel . I need to trace the path in rviz, so I need to convert the velocity to distance and transform it to the world frame.

**Comment by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on 2016-07-04**:
Also in this tutorial, they seem to have taken both X and Y velocity for calculating the odometry

[link text](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom)

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2016-07-05**:
The tutorial does include a y velocity component, so I take it to mean that the simulated data (robot) is not for a differential drive, but perhaps a holonomic type.  Can you post the code for the publisher of the odom? It shouldn't matter but is the robot real or simulated?

**Comment by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on 2016-07-05**:
Hey! I don't have the code though. But it is a real robot. I just have the rosbag file recorded. I guess, when the frame is in map frame, it will have both X and Y velocity. It can have just X velocity when the frame of reference is in robot's frame(base_footprint).  What do you think?